# Is there any way to pass parameters to a binded variable in Vue.JS with moustache syntax

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuetify.js

Let's say i have an HTML of the form:

```
<div>
  {{ GREETING_MESSAGE_FROM_TO }}
</div>
```

And in my data:

```
data() {
  return {
      GREETING_MESSAGE_FROM_TO: 'Hello this message is for {{variable_1}} from {{variable_2}}'
  }
}
```

My question is that is there any way to pass the variables for this template dynamically from within the html. Looking for something similar in Angular.. Something like this format:

```
<div>
  {{ GREETING_MESSAGE_FROM_TO | [variable_1, variable_2] }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use a method since variables are not being computed:

```
methods:{
   GREETING_MESSAGE_FROM_TO(variable_1, variable_2){
      return `Hello this message is for ${variable_1} from ${variable_2}`
   }
}
```

In your template :

```
<div>
  {{ GREETING_MESSAGE_FROM_TO(props1, props2) }}
</div>
```

If those variable are needed to be computed then choose computed instead of methods hook.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways:

```
data() {
  return {
      variable_1: 'Sam',
      variable_2: 'Alex',
      GREETING_MESSAGE_FROM_TO: `Hello this message is for ${this.variable_1} from ${this.variable_2}'
  }
}
```

or better solution:

```
data() {
  return {
      variable_1: 'Sam',
      variable_2: 'Alex'
  }
},
computed() {
      GREETING_MESSAGE_FROM_TO: `Hello this message is for ${this.variable_1} from ${this.variable_2}'
}
```

and

```
<div>
  {{ GREETING_MESSAGE_FROM_TO }}
</div>
```

note that when variable_1 or 2 changes, the greeting updates automatically.

but you can use methods too:

```
methods: {
      GREETING_MESSAGE_FROM_TO: function (variable_1, variable_2) {
          return `Hello this message is for ${variable_1} from ${variable_2}'
    }
}
```

with this usage

```
<div>
  {{ GREETING_MESSAGE_FROM_TO('Sam', 'Alex') }}
</div>
```

or reactive data as args.